# How to retrieve the data which is located between ( and )?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub extractdateincells()
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, str As String
    For Each c In Range("a1:a10")
        For i = 1 To Len(c.Value)
            If Mid(c.Value, i, 1) = "(" Then
                Range("b1:b10") = Mid(c.Value, i + 1, 1)
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I tried to extract the data using above code, but i am not able to get the required answer.
If i have `king(anil434323)hkd3` and `jejrew(3232213)` in cell1 and cell2, then I need to get the answer as `anil434323` and `3232213` in next cells.
What do I need to do to fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own search routine, use `InStr` and `InStrRev`:

```
Sub extractdateincells()
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer, str As String
    Dim OpenPos As Long, ClosePos As Long
    For Each c In Range("a1:a10")
        str = c.Value
        OpenPos = InStr(str, "(")
        ClosePos = InStrRev(str, ")")
        If OpenPos > 0 And ClosePos > 0 Then
            c.Value = Mid(str, OpenPos + 1, ClosePos - OpenPos - 1)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this have to be a macro? Use this formula in cell B1 and copy down:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,")",REPT(" ",99)),FIND("(",A1&"(")+1,99))
```

If it has to be a macro, this should work for you:

```
Sub extractdateincells()

    Dim sCell As String

    With Range("A1:A10")
        sCell = .Cells(1).Address(0, 0, , True)
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(" & sCell & ","")"",REPT("" "",99)),FIND(""(""," & sCell & "&""("")+1,99))"
        .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, 1).Value
    End With

End Sub
```